# How can I change the variable(column) names in R?

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, multiple-columns

How can I change the variable(column) names in R? I couldn't do it with plyr package or any other data manipulation R package.

Comment: Give [mcve]. Eventually use `names(df)[..] <- "newname"` But this relates on `R` and not on `RStudio`

Answer (score 1):

You can also make it like this:

```
df <- data.frame("1", "b", "test")
names(df) <- c("Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the column names:

```
colnames(DataFrame)[colnames(DataFrame)=="Old Column Name"] <- "New Column Name"
```